# Odd and Even list item color

Tags: list, sharepoint-designer, list-view, splistitem

i saw a sharepoint where its list item as a background color (blue) for odd list item number and another (white) for even numbers. I dont know where i can set this.

I looked into designer and i could do it with the ID property and check if the list item is even or odd and then change the background color but the problem is if i do this and they change the way the list is ordered then it will be all messed up. Help anyone ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about XSLTListViewWebPart then there should be a class `ms-alternating` for every second `<tr>` which you can use to select in CSS, like this:

```
.ms-itmhover { background-color: darkblue }
.ms-alternating { background-color: darkred }
```

Another fun way is to use pseudoselects like `:not(.ms-alternating)` or more fun:

```
tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: darkblue }
tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: darkred }
```

But be aware about [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3).